# How can I know if I have Gnome or KDE?

Tags: system-installation

I have installed a Ubuntu 16.04LTS system, how can I know whether Gnome or KDE is installed ? (I searched a bit, but this is not at all intuitive).

Comment: `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`?

Comment: Sytem replies "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity" which is not at all intuitive intuitive, sorry ...

Comment: No need to apologise :) Normally, people do a bit of a research *before* installing an OS.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS comes with the Unity DEsktop.  Kubuntu 16.04 LTS came with the KDE desktop.

Comment: If you didn't  understand the Unity answer;  Unity is a Canonical DEsktop that is a drop-in-replacement for gnome with advantages & of course disadvantages; it isn't gnome but uses the same version of GTK+ /Glib so can use gnome apps without disadvantage (no wasted memory etc)

Comment: @guiverc I installed "gnome-teak-tools", did "Top Bar>clock>show date" and ticked "show date", restarted and nothing happened.

Comment: Because you have the Unity DEsktop; `unity-tweak-tool` will be far more useful. I would expect gnome-tweak to appear if you enter it in the menu/launcher, or from command line, however I'd expect it to only let you change GTK+ settings (note: i don't know; I'm no gnome3/unity fan). You'll find the unity-tweak-tool far more useful for Ubuntu 16.04  (gnome-tweak-tool is more useful if you used Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04 and the gnome desktop).  ps: You can install GNOME-desktop and choose (at login) to run either Unity or Gnome for the session on the same machine; logout when you want to switch etc.

Comment: @guiverc It worked perfectly. Could you copy your last comment as an answer ? so that I could accept it.

Comment: @karel Well it seems a bit different.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is a paradise for egotistical askers of duplicate questions.]---> terrible welcome !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(this follows on from comments. @DK Bose provided

`env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

which confirmed 'Unity' as the DEsktop)

Unity is a Canonical DEsktop that is a drop-in-replacement for gnome with advantages & of course disadvantages; it isn't gnome but uses the same version of GTK+ /Glib so can use gnome apps without disadvantage (no wasted memory etc)

As to tweaking: instead of trying to use 'gnome-tweak-tools' I suggested adding the Unity Tweak Tool

`sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`

as it provides far more options for Unity than gnome-tweak-tool.

Comment: This works and `ècho $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` is faster than `grep`ing your entire `ènv`